# authorization check in the attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to implement a redirect unauthorized user with a check in the proper attribute. To do this I create a class attribute with a constructor with no parameters.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class LoggedAttribute:Attribute
{
    public LoggedAttribute()
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Now assign this attribute to all methods of action that requires authorization.

```
    [Logged]
    public ViewResult SendMessage()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I have a User model with boolean flag IsLoggedIn. How can I check this flag in the class attribute to redirect the user to the authentication page in case of an emitted flag ?

Comment: You don't want to use the built-in `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: Can't understand, why you need this. Why not just use [Authorize] attribute for this porpose?

Comment: I want to use my attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of using a custom authorization attribute like below:

```
 public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
 {    
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {                
            //anything else you'd like to do like log it
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

and then you can redirect them by the following override:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    //disable the redirect
    if(disabled)
    {
        //do something else
    }else{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new
                        { 
                            controller = "Account", 
                            action = "Login" 
                        })
                );
     }
}
```

**UPDATE:**  and you use it like this:

```
[AuthorizeUser]
public ActionResult myAction()
{
     return View();
}
```

Comment: How can I set true value to isAuthorized simple way ?

Comment: I'm sorry could you please elaborate? I don't understand your question.

Comment: When user authentificated - how to disable redirect by means of the minimum writing of a code ?

Comment: I've updated the override method above. see if that answers your question (if I understood it correctly). if not let me know

Comment: (!isAuthorized) - how can I set isAuthorized true ?

Comment: without any checks and validation? or manually log a user in (by knowing their username and password)

Comment: User account stored in database. I can get it everywhere in my code. When I get it and get login and password from page - how as a result of this comparison to authorize the user without creation of numerous program heaps?